# Docker container actively refusing connection

Tags: python, mysql, docker

MySQL error:

```
10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I'm having issues trying to connect to the database from my local machine to the Docker container.

Connection string:

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", port="3306", user="root", password="0000", database="asd")
```

Answer:

Ended up forgetting to add -p 3306:3006 to my run command.

Comment: Where is the database running?  The client?  Have you reviewed the existing SO answers discussing MySQL clients, `localhost`, and Docker?

Comment: Database is hosted in a Docker container as mentioned, and yes I have. There are very little posts regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be your firewall is blocking your port

Check with this command if possibly any firewalls are blocking any ports for your application

```
netstat -ano | findstr -i SYN_SENT
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Got this as the response:
    'TCP    127.0.0.1:6311         127.0.0.1:3306         SYN_SENT        12496'

Isn't the Docker container the one that's refusing the request?